# Is passing an enum value to an int parameter non standard?

Tags: c++

Example:

```
enum SomeEnum
{
   DD,
   PP,
   NN
};

void someFunc(int a)
{
}

int main()
{
  SomeEnum e = DD;
   someFunc(a) // calls someFunc with value 0
  return 0;
}
```

This works in MSVC but is it non standard?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An `enum` has an underlying integer type (the type used to store the value of the `enum`), and the `enum` value can be implicitly converted to that integer type's value.

In your case the underlying type is `int`, and the value is 0. Everything is okay.

Comment: Note that in C++11, this is only true for unscoped enumerations.  For scoped enumerations (`enum class`), there is no implicit conversion to integral type.

Answer (score 0):

The identiﬁers in an enumerator list are declared as constants that have type int and may appear wherever such are permitted.

6.7.2.2 here http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf

Answer (score 0):

It's absolutely valid because, as GManNickG and tomato said, all enums are of type int (in fact, in C, enums ARE ints and you can assign them values outside the scope of the enum.

```
typedef enum _foo
{
   val1 = 57
} foo;
...
foo f = 99; // compiles in C but not C++
```

In fact, most compilers won't complain if the function argument type was bool or float or some other primitive number type because enums act as constant integer values like 0, -1, 200, etc...

What I'd say though, is that, if you have control over someFunc's signature and you want to ensure in C++ that no invalid values are passed in, change it to be

```
void someFunc(SomeEnum a);
```

for more typesafety

Also, always initialize your first enum value at least. I may be wrong on this but, back in the day, the compiler was allowed to pick an arbitrary starting value for your enum. Most of the time it picked 0 but not always. Even if that's not the case, it makes the code a little more self documenting and obvious.

Comment: I didn't say they were all `int`, I said they're an integer type. They may be `unsigned`, `(unsigned) long`, or `(unsigned) long long` depending on the values in the enumerator.